# Add code to the beginning of a macro if the user selects the wrong starting column and give the message "Select a cell from column "E"

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub TryAgainPrint3()
'
' TryAgainPrint3 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:H1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Print").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-3, -2).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Problems").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Range("A1:I1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Print").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Problems").Select
    Range("V5").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Print").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: `if activecell.column <> 5 then | msgbox("select a cell from column E")`?

Comment: This is a [macro-recorder] code dump, not a question. Care to [edit] a bit?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. To clarify I want the macro to run only if a cell in column "E" is selected and Msgbox to say "Select a cell in column E".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the subroutine exit if the user hasn't selected a cell in column E, you can add the following If statement to the top of your code:

```
If ActiveCell.Column <> 5 Then
    MsgBox ("Select a cell in Column E")
    Exit Sub
Else:
End If
```

Does that get you what you need?  You can specify any column, just bear in mind you need to use the column index, not the column itself.  Column E = column 5

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Your help has now made the spreadsheet system valuable in identifying problems in the company. Thank you so much.